# Send Email within Catch inside Constructor

Tags: apex, email, controller, exception

It looks extremely easy, but apparently I can't make this to work.

Not even tried:

- @future, not allowed in contructor
- create log error object, not  allowed in consctructor

I tried:

- inside the catch block in the constructor send email
- in the catch block set some variables and show to the user a panel with a button, under this button there's an action which sends the
  email

am I fighting a lost cause? Thanks for any insight
T.

Comment: How about doing a DML and then based on that calling a workflow to fire an email? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**This is how I would approach it:**
 **1.** Do a `DML` of some sort on the related object. 
 **2.** Call a workflow on the update of that field in the related object. 
 **3.** On the field update, add an `email alert via the workflow`.

**Benefits of doing this:**
 **1.** Your code will become much easier to test.
 **2.** Code will differ from configuration.
 **3.** You can reuse the workflow for other purposes and will be easier to maintain.

To make this more clear I am writing sample pseudo code. 
 
**Page:**

```
  <apex:page controller="AbcController" action="{!doDml}">
      <!-- ... -->
    </apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class AbcController {

  //Constructor
  public AbcController() {
    //non DML calls
  }

  public void doDml() {
    //Your logic
    //your DML 
  }

}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If this is a controller or an extension, I don't believe you can perform DML in the constructor.

Comment: That is correct Jesse - DML's are not permitted inside the constructor but an action tag can be added to the VF page to call the DML.

Comment: @JesseAltman I edited my answer to reflect what I feel could be done to resolve the issue. Do you forsee any issues with it?